# customizing lightSlider slide

Tags: html, css, slider

I am using the light slider jquery plugin to slide the html content. However the plugin works but some slides are mis aligned.

Here is the [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/1998/) regarding this issue.

Here is my **html:**

Here the 4 list items should be displayed as 4 slides, but they are not. Only first and second slides are displaying properly. Somehow two and three are mis aligned.

```
<div class="demo">
    <ul id="light-slider">
        <li>
            <h3>1</h3>
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>Hello, what the hell ?</p>
            <p>Hello, lets put his long terxt.....so long and, so long</p>
            <p>Hello</p>

        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>Second Slide</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Excepteur amet adipisicing fugiat velit nisi.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>Third Slide</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#light-slider").lightSlider({
          item: 1,
          autoWidth: true,
          slideMove: 1, // slidemove will be 1 if loop is true
          slideMargin: 40,

          addClass: '',
          mode: "slide",
          useCSS: true,
          cssEasing: 'ease', //'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',//
          easing: 'linear', //'for jquery animation',////

          speed: 400, //ms'
          auto: true,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          loop: false,
          slideEndAnimation: true,
          pause: 2000,

          keyPress: false,
          controls: true,
          prevHtml: '',
          nextHtml: '',

          rtl:false,
          adaptiveHeight:false,

          vertical:false,
          verticalHeight:500,
          vThumbWidth:100,

          thumbItem:1,
          pager: true,
          gallery: false,
          galleryMargin: 5,
          thumbMargin: 5,
          currentPagerPosition: 'middle',

          enableTouch:true,
          enableDrag:true,
          freeMove:true,
          swipeThreshold: 40,

          responsive : [],

          onBeforeStart: function (el) {},
          onSliderLoad: function (el) {},
          onBeforeSlide: function (el) {},
          onAfterSlide: function (el) {},
          onBeforeNextSlide: function (el) {},
          onBeforePrevSlide: function (el) {}
      });
  });
```

**Output:**
The slide 1 text doesnt fit to screen, it goes off the screen.

[image]

In the second slide, the slide three content is shown in slide two.

[image]
[image]

4th slide is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be miscalculating the **autoWidth**, or when you set it, it goes beyond the width of the slide wrapper so if you change that to **false**, everything aligns correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#light-slider").lightSlider({
          item: 1,
          autoWidth: false,
          slideMove: 1, // slidemove will be 1 if loop is true
          slideMargin: 40,
          ...
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/2757/

Comment: Hi, pull request #302 already fixed this issue. If you are still using this plugin, please check at https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/pulls